# How, if at all, can one parameterize this set of two-dimensional sigmoidal functions?

Tags: calculus, probability, analysis

This question is a bit of a puzzle. I am looking to describe and parameterize the functions
$$f: [0, 1]^2 \rightarrow [0, 1]$$
which satisfy the following constraints:

$$\begin{align}
\forall s < 1: f(s, 0) &= 0 & \forall q > 0: f(1, q) &= 1\\
\forall q < 1: f(0, q) &= 0 & \forall s > 0: f(s, 1) &= 1\\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\forall 0 < s, q < 1&: f(s, q) = f(q, s)\\
\forall 0 < s, q < 1&: f(s, q) = 1 - f(1 - q, 1 - s)\\
\end{align}$$

This function should be continuous and differentiable everywhere on its domain, except for where the boundary conditions are discontinuous: we choose that $f(0, 1) = f(1, 0) = \frac{1}{2}$. Moreover, it should be strictly increasing in both arguments:
$$\forall s < 1, q < 1, 0 < \varepsilon \leq 1 - s, 0 < \delta \leq 1 - q: f(s, q) < f(s + \varepsilon, q + \delta)$$
On top of all of the above, the function should be convex in the lower triangle and concave on the upper triangle (and having second derivative equal to zero on the $s + q = 1$ line).

This makes the functions $f$ a "two-dimensional sigmoid", and in some ways it is similar to a copula. How could one give explicit forms of such functions? Ideally, I'm interested in parameterizing in terms of a (non-decreasing, continuous, differentiable) function from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$ which gives the function values along the $s = q$ line.

As a bonus, I'm interested in all those functions whose second derivative along every line piece where the function is not constant, has at most one root.

I am looking forward to suggestions for approaches!

**Update**: I have now almost found an example of such a function:
$$f(s, q) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sin \left(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2} - |\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2} (s - q)|} \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2} (s + q - 1)\right)$$
Unfortunately, it isn't everywhere differentiable.
Note how the $\sin$ could be interchanged with any sigmoid, as long as the constant ($\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}$) before $s + q - 1$ is adapted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more puzzling, I think I have found at least a good example for the functions in that class. I suspect that when one includes the mentioned bonus requirement, the function below is the only function.

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{2(1-(-1)^n)}{n \pi \sinh(n \pi)} \left( \sin(n \pi x) \sinh(n \pi y) + \sinh(n \pi x) \sin(n \pi y) \right)$$